# Update $_SESSION array value

Tags: php, session

I have select option, if I change the value, I need to update the session array value.

Example, in `$_SESSION` I have two products

| Name | Qtr | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pr1 | 2 | 12 |
| pr2 | 4 | 15 |

I am displaying the array on cart page with select option to change the qty.

if I change the option qty for the first product, it's updating both the product value.

Here is my PHP code

```
var_dump ($_SESSION['addcart'])
```

```
array(2) { 
    ["169aw"]=> array(3) { 
        ["product_id"]=> string(3) "169" 
        ["qty"]=> string(1) "2" 
        ["price"]=> string(3) "189" 
    } 
    
    ["86aw"]=> array(3) { 
        ["product_id"]=> string(2) "86" 
        ["qty"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["price"]=> string(3) "220" 
    }
}
```

Displaying the array in select field

```
$tot_cart = $_SESSION['addcart'];
$keys = array_keys($tot_cart);

for($i = 0; $i < count($tot_cart); $i++) {
    foreach([$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
        $newqty = $tot_cart[$keys[$i]]['qty'];
    }

<form action="<?php echo $base_url?>pages/login-script.php" id="cart-qty-update">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $keys[$i]?>" name="cart-prd-item" class="cart-prd-item">
    <select name="sel-prod-opt" id="sel-prod-opt-val" onchange="update_cart()">
        <option value="1" <?php if($newqty == 1){ echo 'selected';} ?> >1</option>
        <option value="2" <?php if($newqty == 2){ echo 'selected';} ?>>2</option>
        <option value="3" <?php if($newqty == 3){ echo 'selected';} ?>>3</option>
        <option value="4" <?php if($newqty == 4){ echo 'selected';} ?>>4</option>
        <option value="5" <?php if($newqty == 5){ echo 'selected';} ?>>5</option>
        <option value="6" <?php if($newqty == 6){ echo 'selected';} ?>>6</option>
        <option value="7" <?php if($newqty == 7){ echo 'selected';} ?>>7</option>
        <option value="8" <?php if($newqty == 8){ echo 'selected';} ?>>8</option>
        <option value="9" <?php if($newqty == 9){ echo 'selected';} ?>>9</option>
        <option value="10" <?php if($newqty == 10){ echo 'selected';} ?>>10</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

`jQuery` function to get the value of the new option

```
function update_cart(val){
    var cart_id = $('.cart-prd-item').val();
    var cart_qty = $('.sel-prod-opt-val').val();
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost/web/pages/script.php',
        data: {
            cart_id:cart_id,
            cart_qty:cart_qty
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#new_select").html(response); 
            window.location.replace('http://localhost/web/pages/cart.php');
        }
    });
}
```

PHP file to set the value

```
if(isset($_POST['get_option'])){
    $cart_qty = $_POST['cart_qty'];
    $cart_id = $_POST['cart_id'];
   
    $keys = array_keys($_SESSION['addcart']);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['addcart']); $i++) {
        foreach([$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
            $_SESSION['addcart'][$cart_id]['qty'] = $cart_qty;
        }
    }
}
```

If i change the value of the first product, instead of updating the `qty` value of the first product, `qty` value of both the arrays has been updated

Comment: You're looping over all the items in the cart and updating their quantity. You need to also pass the ID of the product through along with the new quantity. With that, you can loop over the items, check if the current item is the one you want to update, and only then update it.

Comment: I added the ID "<input type="text" value="<?php echo $keys[$i]?>" name="cart-prd-item" id="cart-prd-item">" but now its updating only the first product and its not working for second product

Answer (score 0):

Add in select the cart id

```
 <select name="sel-prod-opt" class="sel-prod-opt" data-cart-key="<?php echo $CartKey; ?>" id="sel-prod-opt-val">
```

So in the js update like that

```
$(".sel-prod-opt").on("change", function(){
    var value = $(this).val(),
        CartKey = $(this).attr("data-cart-key");
    //call your ajax for update the cart in session
}
// PHP File like:
$_SESSION[cart][$_POST[CartKey]]['qty'] = $_POST[value];
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you don't need to for or foreach.
you solve this problem as following line.
ofcourse if your cart_id and cart_qty is true then

```
if(isset($_POST['get_option'])){
  $cart_qty = $_POST['cart_qty'];
  $cart_id = $_POST['cart_id'];
  $_SESSION['addcart'][$cart_id]['qty'] = $cart_qty;
}
```